# How to access component method from router

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm performing an Ajax request and I present the data inside a component in the form of a table. From the same component I grab data on click (the `handleClick` function grabs the `id` data), in order to use it for another Ajax request inside another component. I call all the components from React-Router. The problem is that I need the clicked info to use it as a property for my calls that I perform inside the component that does the routing. Is there a way to access it from there?

The `CompTable` component presents a table of data.

```
var CompTable = React.createClass({

 propTypes: {
  compData:   React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
 },

 getInitialState: function() {
  return {id: ''};
 },

 handleClick: function(e) {
  this.setState({id:e})
 },

 render: function() {

  var list = this.props.compData.map(function (comp, i) {
   return (
    <tr key={i+1}>
     <th scope="row">{i+1}</th>
      <td className={comp.id} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, comp.id)}> <Link to={'/competitions/'+comp.league}> {comp.caption} </Link></td>
      <td>{comp.league}</td>
      <td>{comp.numberOfTeams}</td>
     </tr>
    );
   }, this);
```

This is the routing component:

```
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var TeamsWrapper = React.createClass({
 render: function () {
  return (
   <div>
    <Teams id={CompTable.handleClick} />
   </div>
  );
 }
});

var CompetitionsWrapper = React.createClass({
 render: function () {
  return (
   <div>
    <Competitions source="http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/?season=2016" />
   </div>
  );
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
   <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
   <Route path='/competitions' component={CompetitionsWrapper}></Route>
   <Route path='/competitions/:teamLeague' component={TeamsWrapper} ></Route>
  </Route>
 </Router>, app);
```

The `<Teams id={CompTable.handleClick} />` doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I accidentally ran to another problem which probably is responsible for this one. The `handleClick` function doesn't store the id state at all. I can't get `this.state.id` on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you have to move your state to the component, that resolves routing. (You don't have such top-level component now, so you have to create one) In the same component you have to define your handleClick function which you can then pass down to the CompTable as a prop.

Then, when handleClick is triggered, you setState in the top-level component and so you're free to pass desired *id* down to use it in your API call.

Comment: It took me a while to do that, because it was a little more complicated than it sounded. It turned out that I had to return a property value from a grandchild to a parent. But what you're suggesting is excactly the way to do it. Thanks